# (LIBGDX) how to clean the RAM memory that my app uses?

Tags: java, android, memory, libgdx

I have create a game app in libgdx and usually it works well, but sometimes it goes in slow motion, in my opinion is a RAM memory problem. I've a Main class that extends Game.class, in  main class i create a play screen class, when the player died i create again the play screen class. I believe that the RAM memory that the memory has not released and after many death it accumulates, in fact if I run the application with the task manager open  when the death increase memory also increases.

This is the code:

```
public class MyGdxGame extends Game(){
    private PlayScreen play_screen;  
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    public void create(){
    batch=new SpriteBatch();

    play_screen=new PlayScreen(this);

    setScreen(play_screen);

}

public void render(){

    if(play_screen.death==true){

        play_screen=new PlayScreen(this);

        setScreen(play_screen);

    }

}
```

So I did a test:

```
public void render(){

    do{
        play_screen=null;
        play_screen=new PlayScreen(this);
        setScreen(play_screen);
    }while(1!=2);
}
```

I ran the app with the task manager open, memory increases rapidly until it crashes. So how i can clean up the RAM memory?

Comment: garbage collection does release and allocate Memory and you have not access to it.something that you can do is managing RAM in high level programming.

Comment: You've left out so much of your code as to make it impossible to determine what the problem might be.

Comment: 1) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! Most IDEs have a keyboard shortcut specifically for formatting code. 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Many LibGDX objects has to be manually cleared for memory, see [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Memory-management). They implement the interface [Disposable](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Disposable.html) which has the method `#dispose()`.

I don't see you disposing any of your used resources, your SpriteBatch is one of these objects.
When you're done with it call `batch.dispose()`. Setting it to null afterwards is optional, but recommended because using a disposed resource might lead to unintended behavior. The code will look something like this, which should be called when you no longer need it:

```
if(batch != null) {
    batch.dispose();
    batch = null;
}
```

LibGDX memory leaks is almost ever because one or more resources was not disposed

Comment: yes, that was the problem, now i have resolved. Pratically did a test, in MyGdxGame.render() method, i put that code:                             play_screen=new PlayScreen(this);                                                                     so i created new play_screen objects continuously, and when i ran with the task manager i could see that the temporary memory of app increased, instead with play_screen.dispose(); the temporary memory remain stable . So i think i have solved it. Thanks a lot